# How do I access versionInfo from CorDapp code?

Tags: version, corda

Is there any way to access `VersionInfo` from Cordapp code? This appears to be an internal method for the node:

https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/bffac331a37666415b91c0780d811669885a5d48/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/VersionInfo.kt

Answer (score 0):

In Corda most of the features you need are found in the serviceHub which is accessible in flow execution. In this case you would want to access the application context of your CorDapp. Inside the application content you can access information about your CorDapp including the Version of Corda your application is using.

```
// Snippet to get CorDapp version info
System.out.println(getServiceHub().getAppContext().getCordapp().getTargetPlatformVersion()

// Snippet to get Corda Node version info
getServiceHub().getMyInfo().getPlatformVersion()
```

Comment: This works when getting the major version but the full patch information is only available on VersionInfo.